# Store multiple arrays in UserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

Wondering if might be able to store an array within iOS UserDefaults storage. I have a screen with different profiles that will be used as a predefined input during the ordering process. There is no user login system so I plan to use UserDefaults module for this purpose instead of the online database store.

Desired array:

```
[
  "Profile 1" : ["title" : "Ing.",
                 "salutation" : "Herr",
                 "fullname" : "Franz Bernstein Stiglitz"
                 "phone" : "13001300",
                 "email" : "john2doe@example.com",
                ],
  "Profile 2" : ["title" : "Dr.",
                 "salutation" : "Herr",
                 "fullname" : "Joseph Keusch"
                 "phone" : "06606666800",
                 "email" : "jkeusch_1974@example.com",
                ],
]
```

[image]

I have this Struct with Model and using this I am able to store as a single KVS (without "array logic").

```
struct OrderingProfiles {

    static let (titleKey, salutationKey, fullnameKey, phoneKey, emailKey) = ("title", "salutation", "fullname", "phone", "email")
    static let userSessionKey = "com.save.usersession"

    struct OrderingProfile {
        var title: String?
        var salutation: String?
        var fullname: String?
        var phone: String?
        var email: String?

        init(_ json: [String: String]) {
            self.title = json[titleKey]
            self.salutation = json[salutationKey]
            self.fullname = json[fullnameKey]
            self.phone = json[phoneKey]
            self.email = json[emailKey]
        }
    }

    static var saveOrderingProfile = { (title: String, salutation: String, fullname: String, phone: String, email: String) in
        UserDefaults.standard.set([titleKey: title, salutationKey: salutation, fullnameKey: fullname, phoneKey: phone, emailKey: email], forKey: userSessionKey)
    }

    static var getOrderingProfile = { _ -> OrderingProfile in
        return OrderingProfile((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: userSessionKey) as? [String: String]) ?? [:])
    }(())

    static func clearUserData(){
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: userSessionKey)
    }

}
```

Comment: Better to make your struct Codable and save the json data to a file inside your app preferences folder

Comment: To add to Leo's comment, UserDefaults is not for app data. It's for little things like preferences.

Comment: @rmaddy I understand. What do you think about Core Data in this case?

Comment: Depends on how much data you have.

Comment: @rmaddy I started using [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift). It perfectly fits my needs.

Answer (score -1):

if your responce is like this

```
[
      "Profile" : ["title" : "Ing.",
                     "salutation" : "Herr",
                     "fullname" : "Franz Bernstein Stiglitz"
                     "phone" : "13001300",
                     "email" : "john2doe@example.com",
                    ],
      "Profile" : ["title" : "Dr.",
                     "salutation" : "Herr",
                     "fullname" : "Joseph Keusch"
                     "phone" : "06606666800",
                     "email" : "jkeusch_1974@example.com",
                    ],
    ]
```

Try this code using third party model mapping
library link:-   https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper

**1) Model Class**

```
import UIKit
import ObjectMapper
class ProfileModel:NSObject , Mappable , NSCoding {
    var Profile:[ProfileData]?


    required init?(map: Map) {

    }
     required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.Profile =  aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:"Profile") as? [ProfileData]
    }
    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

        aCoder.encode(Profile, forKey: "Profile")
    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {

        Profile           <- map["Profile"]
    }
}

class ProfileData:NSObject , Mappable , NSCoding {


    var title:String?
    var salutation:String?
    var fullname:String?
    var phone:String?
    var fullname:String?



    required init?(map: Map) {

    }


    //==========================================
    //MARK: - NSCoder Initializer Methods
    //==========================================


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        self.title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as? String
        self.salutation =  aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:"salutation") as? String
        self.fullname =  aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:"fullname") as? String
        self.phone =  aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:"phone") as? String
        self.email =  aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:"email") as? String



    }


    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

        aCoder.encode(title, forKey: "title")
        aCoder.encode(salutation, forKey: "salutation")
        aCoder.encode(fullname, forKey: "fullname")
        aCoder.encode(phone, forKey: "phone")
        aCoder.encode(email, forKey: "email")


    }


    //==========================================
    //MARK: - Mappable Protocol Methods
    //==========================================


    func mapping(map: Map) {

        title           <- map["title"]
        salutation      <- map["salutation"]
        fullname        <- map["fullname"]
        phone           <- map["phone"]
        email           <- map["email"]

    }



}
```

Save data in UserDefaults

1) Save Data code

```
var arrayProfile:[ProfileData] = []
var arrprofile:[ProfileModel] = []
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

for data in arrprofile
{
 arrayProfile.append(data)
}

let saveProfileData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: arrayProfile)
defaults.set(saveProfileData, forKey: "profile")
defaults.synchronize()
```

2) Retrive Data

```
var arrayProfile:[ProfileData] = []
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
 guard let profile_data = defaults.object(forKey: "profile") as? NSData else {
            print("'profile' not found in UserDefaults")
                            return
        }
        guard let placesArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: profile_data as Data) as? [ProfileData] else {
                            print("Could not unarchive from profile_data")
                            return
                        }

        for place in placesArray
        {
            arrayProfile.append(place)

        }
```

In my case working 100% try this

Comment: Although technically this may do what the OP asked for; the reason I'm downvoting is for future viewers as this is abusing user defaults. There are many ways to store data locally on iOS and saving to user defaults isn't one of them.

Comment: i am agree with you. but question is Store multiple arrays in UserDefaults so that is the reason i am post this answer